# How to delete files filtered out by awk

Tags: find, awk, xargs

I have the following files in a directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  46 Apr 22 12:09 bills.50.1.3G.MO.X.20120422120453.Z
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  28 Apr 22 12:15 bills.50.1.3G.MO.X.20120422120953.Z
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  46 Apr 22 12:20 bills.50.1.3G.MO.X.20120422121453.Z
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  46 Apr 22 12:25 bills.50.1.3G.MO.X.20120422121953.Z
```

Where the fifth column is the file's size. I wish to delete all files which size is 46. In order to filter out these files I used the following command:

```
ls -ltr | awk '$5 ~ /46/ {print $0}'
```

Which works fine. But now I want to delete all files which were filtered out, so I add the following to the above command:

```
ls -ltr | awk '$5 ~ /46/ {print $0}' | xargs rm
```

However it gives me the following error:

```
rm: invalid option -- w
```

It seems that I have to use `find` over `ls` so I will get the output in the below format:

```
./bills.50.1.3G.MO.X.20120421050453.Z
./bills.50.1.3G.MO.X.20120421154953.Z
./bills.50.1.3G.MO.X.20120419133452.Z
```

But then I have no way to filter the files by its parameters.
How this task could be done?

Comment: Btw, `find` could also do this, i.e. something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -size 46c -delete` (at least GNU find can)

Comment: @sr_ That's an interesting option. I will keep that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Please [don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  @sr_ You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @jw013 Thanks for the link! I'm familiar with this issue, however I couldn't figure out how to avoid using `ls` here.

Comment: @EugeneS ... except sr_ has already shown you exactly how to do this safely with `find`.  Why don't you just use the suggested command?  It is *never* necessary to use `ls` for manipulating files (at least I have yet to run into such a situation) since `find` and shell globbing cover nearly all cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two bugs:

1. You are comparing for a size that *contains* `46`; you want it to be *equal to* 46.
2. You are printing the entire line, when you want only the filename.

And an additional issue:  what is the point of `-ltr` to sort the `ls` output when you aren't using the sort order?

You want to do something like

```
ls -l | awk '$5 == "46" {print $9}' | xargs rm
```

Except you *don't* want to do that, because while it might be safe at the moment, parsing `ls` output is unreliable.  Use an appropriate tool such as

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -size 46c -delete # requires GNU find
```

(Doing this portably is more annoying, since POSIX `find` doesn't have `-maxdepth` or `-size` that operates in units other than blocks.  Better to write a script in a Perl/Python/Ruby/etc. that can use a proper directory scan that won't get in trouble with special characters in filenames.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and mentioning ALL the bugs! You're absolutely right, it works fine now. Regarding the `-ltr`, I guess it's just a bad habit.

Comment: Also note the comment above about parsing `ls` output, which I let pass; it is really not a good idea, due to the possibility of spaces and other special characters in filenames.

Comment: I know that but I couldn't think about a way to avoid this. If you can edit your answer and describe a way to perform this task without using `ls` I will be grateful. Thanks again!

Comment: I would advise using `$NF` (always referring to the last field) instead of `$9`.

Comment: @jippie, that's still not going to work if there's whitespace in the name.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, to remove all files of size 26 in the current directory (first line) or the current directory and its subdirectories (second line), use the `L` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
rm *(L26)
rm **/*(L26)
```

With GNU or FreeBSD/NetBSD/OSX find:

```
find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o -type f -size 26c -exec rm {} +
find . -type f -size 26c -exec rm {} +
```

Portably:

```
find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o -type f -exec sh -c '[ $(wc -c <"$0") -eq 26 ] && rm -- "$0"' {} \;
find . -type f -exec sh -c '[ $(wc -c <"$0") -eq 26 ] && rm -- "$0"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` is the best option here. you can use [`stat`](http://man.cx/stat) to find the file size without using `ls`

```
for file in *; do
  (( $(stat -c %s "$file") == 46 )) && rm "$file"
done
```